# WPF Bind DependencyProperty to another DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView within a UserControl, which is able to Scroll + Zoom and Drag. (Because the TreeView is really huge) Because the Scroll/Zoom/Drag UserControl is listening to

1. OnScrollViewerScrollChanged
2. OnMouseLeftButtonUp
3. OnMouseLeftButtonUp
4. OnPreviewMouseWheel
5. OnMouseLeftButtonDown
6. OnMouseMove

the TreeViewItems are not able to receive any mouse input. Therefore, I created a DependencyProperty for a TreeViewItem, so called IsMouseHover. That DP toggles between true and false, if the mouse enters or leaves the TreeViewItem.

The ScrollZoomDrag UserControl also has a DP, so called "Active", which subscribes or unsubscribes all the mentioned events above.

Now I would like to bind the TreeViewItem's "IsMouseHover" to the ScrollZoomDrag's Control "Active" DP.

```
    <controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
    <controls:OrgTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
        <controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <controls:VisualElement DataContext="{Binding}">
                    <Style TargetType="controls:ScrollDragZoomControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:VisualElement}, Path=IsMouseHover}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Active" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:VisualElement}, Path=IsMouseHover}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Active" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </controls:VisualElement>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:OrgTreeView>
</controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
```

With the solution above, the ScrollZoomDrag's DP "Active" doesn't get toggled at all. Am I missing something or is there a better approach?

**UPDATE**

**ScrollZoomDrag.xaml.cs**

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Active", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollDragZoomControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback(ActiveChanged)));

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveProperty, value); }
    }

    public static void ActiveChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ScrollDragZoomControl scrollDragZoomControl = (ScrollDragZoomControl)obj;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            scrollDragZoomControl.StartListen();
        else scrollDragZoomControl.StopListen();
    }
```

**VisualElement.xaml.cs**

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseHoverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseHover", typeof(bool), typeof(VisualElement), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public VisualElement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseEnter += VisualElement_MouseEnter;
        MouseLeave += VisualElement_MouseLeave;
    }

    public bool IsMouseHover
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseHoverProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsMouseHoverProperty, value); }
    }

    private void VisualElement_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseHover = false;
    }

    private void VisualElement_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseHover = true;
    }
```

**Approach 2: (Doesn't work either)**

```
    <controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
    <controls:ScrollDragZoomControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="controls:ScrollDragZoomControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:VisualElement}, Path=IsMouseHover}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Active" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </controls:ScrollDragZoomControl.Style>
    <controls:OrgTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <controls:VisualElement DataContext="{Binding}">                   
                </controls:VisualElement>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:OrgTreeView>
</controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
```

Comment: currently `<Style TargetType="controls:ScrollDragZoomControl">` is assigned to controls:VisualElement.Content (unless contentProperty was changes). is it intended or some tags are missing (e.g. `<controls:VisualElement.Style><Style TargetType="controls:ScrollDragZoomControl"> etc`)?

Comment: This was intended. Because if I add <controls:VisualElement.Style> ... I receive the exception:

""TargetType 'ScrollDragZoomControl'" does not equal the type "VisualElement"."

Comment: ok. binding btw 2 DP is a common thing actually : `Active="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:VisualElement}, Path=IsMouseHover}"`. Or in a setter: `<Setter Property="Active" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:VisualElement}, Path=IsMouseHover}"`

Comment: That doesn't work either. IsMouseHover gets toggled when I set a breakpoint. But Active doesn't recieve the DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs

Comment: I added more information to the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `ScrollDragZoomControl` inherit from `VisualElement`?

Comment: Also, to clarify, the `ScrollDragZoomControl` is the parent of the entire treeview? So the so the visual tree is something like `ScrollDragZoomControl` -> `OrgTreeView` -> Children?

Comment: ScrollDragZoomControl inherits from UserControl. And yes. ScrollDragZoomControl -> OrgTreeView -> OrgTreeItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a binding with `Mode=OneWayToSource` :

```
IsMouseHover="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:ScrollDragZoomControl}, 
                       Path=Active, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

```
<controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
  <controls:OrgTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
    <controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <controls:VisualElement DataContext="{Binding}" 
             IsMouseHover="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:ScrollDragZoomControl}, 
                                    Path=Active, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
         </controls:VisualElement>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </controls:OrgTreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:OrgTreeView>
</controls:ScrollDragZoomControl>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Do you know why the 1st and 2nd Approach did not work? Still wondering

Comment: @ThomasChristof, I will try to explain. As I commented before `<Style TargetType="controls:ScrollDragZoomControl">` in the orginal version is misplaced and not applied to anything. In the version after edit binding to `AncestorType=controls:VisualElement` cannot work because ZoomControl doesn't have VisualElement parent . VisualElements are nested. To complicate thing they are generated dynamically by TreeView template.

Comment: Binding can have a single Source. We need one ZoomControl to receive values from many VisualElements. Binding with `Mode=OneWayToSource` placed on VisualElement invert the direction and makes VisualElements to report to a parent ZoomControl when their state changes

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to set that Active property binds TwoWay by default so it can register every change

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Im not sure, but maybe it helps to notify the change, or you need to set  it in xaml `mode=TwoWay`

Comment: Did both and didn't help.

Comment: Aha, i didn't ment to post as answer, but can't comment on others.